# POST (Internal Server Error) using CSRF token

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

With the help of Jquery ajax i am trying to edit the data in the form.
According to other solutions, i have already included csrf token in both meta and ajax setup.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

In header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

jQuery

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{url('api/edit-data')}}",
  data: {
    id: id,
    name: name,
    contact: contact,
    email: email,
    valley: valley,
    paddress: paddress,
    taddress: taddress,
    qualification: qualification,
    ts: ts,
    experiences: experiences,
    tob: tob,
    es: es,
    level: level,
    ey: ey,
    cn: cn,
    cv: cv,
  },


  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res.sessiondata);
    //  alert('successful');
  }
});
```

controller

```
 public function editdata(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request->id;
        $data['name'] = $request->name;
        $data['contact'] = $request->contact;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['valley'] =$request->valley;
        $data['paddress'] = $request->paddress;
        $data['taddress'] = $request->taddress;
        $data['qualification'] = $request->qualification;
        $data['ts'] =  $request->ts;
        $data['experiences'] = $request->experiences;
        $data['tob'] = $request->tob;
        $data['es'] = $request->es;
        $data['level'] = $request->level;
        $data['ey'] = $request->ey;
        $data['cn'] = $request->cn;
        $data['cv'] = $request->cv;
        if(cv::find($id)->update($data))
        {
            return response([
                'sessiondata' => $data
            ]);
        }else{
        return response([
            'sessiondata'=> $request->name
        ]);
        }

    }
```

Actual error

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/edit-data 500 (Internal Server Error)

There's already a lots of solution regarding this error.
I have followed them accordingly but i still get this error.
I have already include csrf_token both in header in jquery too.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the error message? You can look at `storage/logs` directory to get `laravel.log`file to see the context of the error. If no log exists, then maybe you have write permissions issue.

Comment: i think you are not getting an error because of CSRF. your error must be regarding someting else. post error message that you have got.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz In my storage/logs it says  call to a member function update() on null

Comment: So your `cv::find($id)` returns `null`. You can use `findOrFail` and surround it with `try/catch` and return a proper response in `catch` part.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,try This.
var token = "{{csrf_token()}}",

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "{{url('api/edit-data')}}",  
  data: {
    _token:token,
    id: id,
    name: name,
    contact: contact,
    email: email,
    valley: valley,
    paddress: paddress,
    taddress: taddress,
    qualification: qualification,
    ts: ts,
    experiences: experiences,
    tob: tob,
    es: es,
    level: level,
    ey: ey,
    cn: cn,
    cv: cv,
  },
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res.sessiondata);
    //  alert('successful');
  }
});
```

generate token in variable before ajax call.

Comment: and if your response data is json then add ** dataType:'json' ** in AJAX

Answer (score 0):

When submitting data, you could add the token as follow:

```
var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
var password = $("input[name=contact]").val();
var email = $("input[name=email]").val();

... other fields ...

/* I would change here the url() helper by route() with route name */

$.ajax({
    url: "{{url('api/edit-data')}}",
    method: "post",
    dataType : "json",
    data : { _token : "{{ csrf_token() }}", name: name, contact: contact,
                email: email, ...    },
    success:function(data){

          console.log(data.sessiondata);

    }
    error:function(data){

          console.log(data.sessiondata);

    }

});
```

Is Cv your model class? If so, in the controller you can get data just like this:

```
public function editdata(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->except('_token');

    $result = Cv::where('id', $id)->update($data);

    if($result)
    {
        return response()->json(['sessiondata' => $data]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['sessiondata'=> $request->name], 400);
    }
}
```

cheers!